# Guest orders didn't link after register

Tags: magento2

I've a problem in my website, when the customer order as guest then create account after purchase the order didn't appear !

Could you please advise how to fix it ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using for Magento 2? To reproduce the case, you need to check or purchase to proceed with the order as a guest and check if the Order appears in the customer dashboard after creating an account for the same user. I have reproduced and tested it on Magento 2.4.4 and 2.4.5, which are working fine.

This shows that order is not assign to customer when creating the account.

**Steps To reproduce**

1: Disable any extension related to the customer or order checkout, which can cause an order to assign to the customer.

2: Manually assign the order from Admin Dashboard to the customer to check if it's working fine.

3: Please check logs if there is something error.

4: Check the order email and customer email is the same.

5: Disable guest checkout and allow customers to create accounts first.

An this happens due to two different situations:

1: The user buy as guest (there's no option on checkout to create the account immediately), then just after it order being confirmed, he see a big button: "Create an Account".

In this situation, the order should be associated IMO.
But some of our client's customers are not being associated to their orders.

2: The user buy as guest, leaves the store, a few hours/days later create the account, with the same email as the order.

In this case, the order should not be linked, since it might be a privacy leak (if email confirmation is not required, I would see all guest orders without necessarily be the customer)

Please have a look into it: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13493

Thanks

Comment: Hi Dear, I've checked everything and I think it's common Magento issue.